# Is there a way to have multiple controllers for a symfony 1.4 module?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a situation where I have a base controller (a base actions.php file) in Symfony 1.4. I want to create another controller, for the same module, that extends that base controller.

I need to extend that base controller because I want to customize the behavior of certain visitors, that are identified based on an ID in the URL.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another controller class for the same module, I think it's impossible in symfony.

I guess the easiest solution for you is to create another method in the same class, and then invoque it from the base one.

By Example: actions.class.php:

```
public function executeBaseAction(sfWebRequest $request) {

   .. if($user....) then return $this->executeCustomAction($request);

}

public function executeCustomAction(sfWebRequest $request) {
  // $this->setTemplate('anotherTemplate?');

}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I was hoping for a more elegant solution with inheritance or something like that... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Nop. Symfony searches for actions.class.php file in the actions folder. And that class name should match "module_folder_name"Actions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add another controller class for the same module.

You could include several files in your action directory in this way:

In action1Action.class.php

```
class action1Action extends sfAction
{
    public function execute($request) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

This will use  template action1Success.php

In action2Action.class.php

```
class action2Action extends sfAction
{
    public function execute($request) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

This will use  template action2Success.php